# iphone SDK NSTimer - Why do I need more than one?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

This is an embarrassing question but it involes Xcode and the iPhone SDK.

Why would I need to set more than one timer?  And do 2 timers take up more 'tics' than 1 timer or are they all based on the same master internal clock?

Is it better to add 1 timer routine and just have it call all the things I need to make happen or have 5 or 6.   I'm not new to programing but I'm completely new to xCode and just trying to wrap my head around it.

Eg.  If I have a timer updating the clock on the screen, and I also want to update the GPS position,  is there any reason not to have the same timer update both?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppressed the xcode tag because it has nothing to do with the development tool but with the framework

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is that timer delegate will operate in separate threads. So in your case, when only one timer is used, if the GPS acquisition takes to much time, your screen will feel unresponsive because the clock will be unregularly updated.

Comment: Timer delegates get called back in the same thread the timer was created on (usually the main thread).